# How to test if ssh server allows passwords?

Tags: ssh, security, password

I want to test whether or not an ssh server allows passwords and immediately close the connection without actually attempting a login.

Something like this:

```
allows_password=$(ssh --some-option example.com)
if [ -z "$allows_password" ]; then
  echo "Insecure Server Options"
else
  echo "Insecure Password Access is not Allowed, Great!"
fi
```

I've actually done this once before, but I couldn't find old script or docs. Sad day. :-/

Comment: Are you sure? The ssh server can be configured to allow passwords for some users but not others. So you at least have to send a username to the server. At that point it will attempt to authenticate you...

Comment: `ssh -v` will output `debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password`, however @MichaelHampton is right, its dependent on user. Some form of ansible/puppet to enforce practices would suite you better.

Comment: I'm developing https://telebit.cloud, which enables remote access via ssh, among other things. People typically have very poor passwords on their personal computers, so I want to make sure I have a way to test for bad defaults and display a warning, in addition to checking `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found my old script:

```
ssh -v -n \
  -o Batchmode=yes \
  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
  -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
  DOES_NOT_EXIST@localhost 2>&1 | grep password
```

- The `-o Batchmode=yes` option causes a non-interactive mode where a fallback to password results in failure.
- The `-v` causes the authentication methods to be displayed (among other things).
- The `-n` causes ssh to not open a shell (often used with tunneling), which in this case will cause it to immediately exit (just in case you're connecting to a honeypot or a service like serveo.net that allows clients without authentication)
- `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` and `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` automatically accepts the host without writing it to the known-hosts file.
- `2>&1` forwards debug messages (stderr) to the logging system (stdout) so that `grep` can do its magic

If password authentication is enabled for some users, it will shows as enabled for all users (but fail after the prompt), as far as I can tell. I suspect this is so that you can't positively id that a user exists on the system.

And so that I don't lose it again: https://coolaj86.com/articles/testing-if-ssh-allows-passwords/